# Complex Integration : $\int_1^{1+i}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Integrate alonf the line segment from $z=1$ to $z=1+i$ :
>   $$\int_1^{1+i}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$$

If I integrate, it is just the identity $tan^{-1}z$, but the answer to this question is $$\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan2+\frac{i}{4}\log5$$ which I don't understand how they got?

Comment: Remember, these are line integrals, so you need to parametrize the line segment, say $z=r(t)$ so that you have $$\int_\Gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_0^1f(r(t))r'(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: You also need to choose a good branch cut for the arctangent in the complex plane to use it as a primitive.

Comment: @Clayton but i thought i dont need to use $$\int_\Gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_0^1f(r(t))r'(t)\,dt.$$ because there is an antiderivative for that function ?

Comment: @ABlumenthal Hm, I havent learned any branch cuts for arctan yet, I just learned an extensive amount of branch cuts on log. I will need to google that.

Comment: @Q.matin: you only use the antiderivative when you know that the integral is independent of path, which means that the integral along any closed path going through the two endpoints is zero.  That is not the case, however, because of the poles at $z=\pm i$.  So you need to parametrize the path and evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$${1\over 1+z^2}={1\over 2i}\left({1\over z-i}-{1\over z+i}\right)={1\over 2i}\>{d\over dz}\log{z-i\over z+i}\ .$$
The quotient ${z-i\over z+i}$ is negative real only on the segment $[-i,i]$. Therefore the principal value ${\rm Log}$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the segment $\sigma$ connecting $1$ and $1+i$, and  we are allowed to write
$$\int_\sigma{dz\over 1+z^2}={1\over 2i}\>{\rm Log}{z-i\over z+i}\biggr|_1^{1+i}={1\over 2i}\bigl({\rm Log}{1\over 1+2i}-{\rm Log}{1-i\over1+i}\bigr)\ .$$
Now use ${\rm Log}z= \log|z|+ i\>{\rm Arg} z$ to arrive at the stated result.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be parameterized by writing $z=1+it$:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{i}{(1+ti)^2+1}dt = \int_0^1 \frac{2 i + 2 t - i t^2}{4+t^4}dt$$
$$ = \int_0^1 \frac{2 t}{t^4+4} + i\int_0^1 \frac{2-t^2}{t^4+4}dt$$
$$ = \frac{i}{2} \arctan(1/2) - \frac{\log 5}{4} = 
\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan2+\frac{i}{4}\log5$$

Comment: Something went wrong in the intermediate result; I think the $\mathrm i$ should be in the second term, and the sign should be $+$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $z=1+i t$, $dz = i dt$.  Then the integral is

$$\begin{align}i \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1+(1+i t)^2} &= i \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{2+i 2 t -t^2} \\ &= -i \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(t-(1+i))(t+(1-i))}\\ &= -\frac{i}{2} \int_0^1 dt \left (\frac{1}{t-(1+i)} - \frac{1}{t+(1-i)} \right ) \\ &= -\frac{i}{2} \left [ \log{ \left ( \frac{t-(1+i)}{t+(1-i)} \right )} \right ]_0^1 \\ &= -\frac{i}{2} \left [ \log{ \left ( \frac{-i}{2-i} \right )} - \log{ \left ( \frac{-(1+i)}{1-i} \right )} \right ]\\ &= -\frac{i}{2}\log{ \left ( \frac{i (1-i)}{(2-i)(1+i)} \right )}\\ &= \frac{i}{2}\log{(2-i)} \end{align}$$

Now write $2-i$ as $\sqrt{5} e^{i (\pi - \arctan{(1/2)})} = \sqrt{5} e^{i ((\pi/2) - \arctan{2})}$  Then

$$i \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1+(1+i t)^2} = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \arctan{2} + i \frac{\log{5}}{4}$$